# PHP - Fetch multiple URLs by chunks

Tags: php, curl

My web application needs to parse remote resources from multiple remote servers. The problem is that the output of those remote servers is long / staged. I hence need a piece of code implementing the following logic:

- Populate array `$links_array` with a set of links.
- Some code here....
- For  `$i` in `count($links_array)`
  `$results_array[$i] = {what has been output until now **without** waiting for full response}
- Some code here....

The answer must not use extensions (except cURL) and work on PHP 5.3.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need an asynchronous method of download links. You can look into the Guzzle Library (https://blog.madewithlove.be/post/concurrent-http-requests/). Another option is to use multi curl: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php